# Blackberry - how to define screen title height?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, rim-4.5

is there a possibility to define somehow title's height?

The main problem is a separator that is located under the actual title. So, possibly there is possibility to define somehow the separator's height.

API 4.5

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the blackberry sdk, however knowing which api version would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this myself and the only way I know of to get around it is to override the (undocumented) method in MainScreen:

```
protected void applyTheme() {
    // leave this empty
}
```

This prevents the theme from setting colors and also seems to get rid of the separator between the title and main content.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But I am getting another interesting issues. If I do later screen layout change (like deleting some fields and adding new ones), the Theme looks like is returning back.

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen that happen before

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [setExtent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setExtent%28int,%20int%29) method.

Comment: well, still I see separator. And it's height difficult to define.

Answer (score 0):

To simply get title height try this:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    public Scr() {
        setTitle("Hello!");
        Manager contentManager = getMainManager();
        Manager screenManager = contentManager.getManager();
        Field titleField = screenManager.getField(0);
        int height = titleField.getPreferredHeight();
        add(new LabelField(String.valueOf(height)));
    }
}
```

And to define title yourself, try to put custom field into [setTitle](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/index.html)

Comment: I have used following approach:
1. defined actual height of title (like the way you described)
2. retrieved height of separator: 
   new SeparatorField().getPreferredHeight()
3. But still I am losing somewhere one pixel.